# Create a table in thymeleaf

Tags: html, html-table, each, thymeleaf

I'm new to thymeleaf and am trying to make a simple table using an array and an each loop.

My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Smoke Tests</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" style="width:300px">
    <tr>
        <td>Test Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="smokeTest : ${smokeTests}">
        <td>
            th:text="${smokeTest.name}">A Smoke Test'
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically my problem is that I can't run the loop as `<td>`s within `<tr>`s. Is there any way that this code could work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple solution which comes to mind first:

```
<th:block th:each="smokeTest : ${smokeTests}">
    <tr>
        <td th:text="${smokeTest.name}">A Smoke Test'</td>
    </tr>
</th:block>
```

Details: http://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew21.html#bloc

Comment: This doesnt work becase the th:text has no relation to the loop.

Answer (score 14):

You must put th:text as an attribute of a tag, so

```
<tr th:each="smokeTest : ${smokeTests}">
   <td th:text="${smokeTest.name}">A Smoke Test'</td>
</tr>
```

should run.

Answer (score 1):

Although, it's late answer.
It's work more specifically, like

```
<tr th:each="smokeTest : ${smokeTests}">
   <td><p th:text="${smokeTest.name}"></p></td>
</tr>
```